# XAException occurred

Tags: java, websphere, rad

I am facing this exception in Websphere App server.
I am new to this. I am working in java environment/ RAD 7.5/ App server 7.0

### Kindly help

The transaction service encountered an error on an xa_recover operation. The resource was com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl@21e521e5. The error code was XAER_RMERR. The exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException

---

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

I see this quite often in my logs. After restart usually. You probably don't have 'Authentication alias for XA recovery' configured in your datasorce, or user don't have permissions to access XA-specific views in Oeacle DB.

So create a user and grant privileges:

```
grant select on pending_trans$ to <user>;
grant select on dba_2pc_pending to <user>;
grant select on dba_pending_transactions to <user>;
grant execute on dbms_system to <user>;  (If using Oracle 10.2.0.3 or lower JDBC driver)
grant execute on dbms_xa to <user>; (If using Oracle 10.2.0.4 or higher JDBC driver)
```

and set this user to xa-recovery alisas for XA-datasources. You should also make sure XA is configured for your Oracle instance, consult DBA.

More info [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196663)